# SQL cast char as number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'This is a FUTURES item. ' to data type int.

What's wrong with the `CAST`?

```
UPDATE STOCK 
SET DESC2 = 'This is a FUTURES item. ' + LEFT(DESC1, 4) + 'futures will begin arriving in ' + (CAST(LEFT(DESC1, 4) as INT) + 3)
WHERE ISNUMERIC(LEFT(DESC1, 4)) = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator `+` is overloaded.  When *any* operand is a number, then it is treated as addition.  Given what you want to do, you need to re-convert the value back to a string:

```
UPDATE STOCK
    SET DESC2 = 'This is a FUTURES item. ' + LEFT(DESC1, 4) + 'futures will begin arriving in ' + CAST(CAST(LEFT(DESC1, 4) as INT) + 3 as VARCHAR(255))
WHERE ISNUMERIC(LEFT(DESC1, 4)) = 1;
```

Although this query will probably work, there is no *guarantee* (in SQL Server) that the `WHERE` occurs before the `set`.  That means that you could still get a type conversion error.  The solution in more recent versions is `try_convert()`.  Or, you can use a `case` statement:

```
UPDATE STOCK
    SET DESC2 = 'This is a FUTURES item. ' + LEFT(DESC1, 4) + 'futures will begin arriving in ' +
                (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(DESC1, 4)) = 1
                      THEN CAST(CAST(LEFT(DESC1, 4) as INT + 3) as VARCHAR(255))
                 END)
WHERE ISNUMERIC(LEFT(DESC1, 4)) = 1;
```

Comment: @Gordon You probably should have emphasize the **no guarantee** part a little more...